# Verilog if-else statements

Tags: if-statement, verilog, hdl

I'm  trying to write a module for a BCD counting stop watch. when I check the syntax I get errors saying:

```
ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "../counter.v" line 24 expecting 'end', found 'else'
ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "../counter.v" line 25 unexpected token: '='
ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "../counter.v" line 25 unexpected token: '+'
ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "../counter.v" line 25 expecting 'endmodule', found '1'
```

in the middle of my code. I'm not quite sure where the error is coming from and have tried to implement more begin/end but that did not fox the problem. Here is my code currently:

```
module BCDCount(en, clk, rst, direction, cTenths, cSec, cTS, cMin);
    input en, clk, rst, direction;
    output [3:0] cTenths, cSec, cTS, cMin;
    reg [3:0] cTenths, cSec, cTS, cMin;

always @(posedge clk)
if(en)
begin

    if(direction == 0)

        if(cMin== 4'b 1001)
                cMin <= 4'b 0000;
            if(cTS == 4'b 0101)
                cTS <= 4'b 0000;
                cMin = cMin +1;

                if(cSec == 4'b 1001)
                    cSec <= 4'b 0000;
                    cTS = cTS +1;
                    if(cTenths == 4'b 1001)
                        cTenths <= 4'b 0000;
                        cSec = cSec+1;
                    else 
                        cTenths = cTenths +1;
                else
                    cSec = cSec+1;
            else
                cTS = cTS + 1;

    if(direction == 1)

        if(cMin== 4'b 0000)
            cMin <= 4'b 1001;
            if(cTS == 4'b 0000)
                cTS <= 4'b 1001;
                cMin = cMin -1;
                if(cSec == 4'b  0000)
                    cSec <= 4'b 1001;
                    cTS = cTS -1;
                        if(cTenths == 4'b 0000)
                            cTenths <= 4'b 1001;
                            cSec = cSec-1;
                        else
                            cTenths = cTenths -1;
                else
                    cSec = cSec-1;
            else
                cTS = cTS - 1;

end
    always @(posedge rst)
        begin
            cMin <= 0;
            cTS <= 0;
            cSec <= 0;
            cTenths <= 0;
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: You need begin-end around every single if-else. Check out the last example in this link: https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/if_statement/

Answer (score 2):

Based on your indenting structure, it looks like you expect that for this code

```
  ...
        if(cTS == 4'b 0101)
            cTS <= 4'b 0000;
            cMin = cMin +1;
                if(cTenths == 4'b 1001)
  ...
```

`Cmin = cMin + 1` will be executed in the case that `cTS == 4'b0101`. However, in Verilog, `if` statements only apply to the statement immediately preceding them (just like in C). To make them apply to multiple statements, we need to wrap those statements in `begin`-`end` blocks (just like `{}` in C).

So, you're getting errors that your code has an `else` statement, but it can't find the matching `if`!

You'll want to use the following:

```
  ...
        if(cTS == 4'b 0101)
        begin
            cTS <= 4'b 0000;
            cMin = cMin +1;
                if(cTenths == 4'b 1001)
            ...
        end
        else
  ...
```

**Edit:** 
Also of note - you're mixing blocking (`=`) and non-blocking (`<=`) assignments in your `always` block. For clocked `always` blocks, you should (basically) always use non-blocking assignments. Move any sequential assignment to their own `always@(*)` block.

You're also going to get errors that signals have multiple drivers, since you assign some signals values in multiple always blocks.

Comment: The SO also put the reset logic in a separate always block which is a big no-no for RTL. It should be moved into one always block: `always @(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin if (rst) begin /* reset code here */ end else begin /* sequential code here */ end end`